# Calling translate.translate.setTranslation inside http request

Tags: angular, http, typescript, get

I am performing a get request and inside of the function I am using `translate.setTranslation(param)`

EXAMPLE:

```
getUserLabels() {
if (navigator.language === 'it') {
  this.browser_language = 'it-IT';
} else {
  this.browser_language = 'en-US';
}

let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  let apiURL = `my url`;
  this.http.get(apiURL)
    .toPromise()
    .then(
      res => { // Success
        this.data = res;
        this.translate.setDefaultLang(this.browser_language);
        this.translate.setTranslation(this.browser_language, {"Fail": "pippo"});

        resolve();
      },
      msg => { // Error
        reject(msg);
      }
    );
});
return promise;
```

}

But actully the call to `setTranslation()` is not working, so it is printing " Fail " and not " pippo ".
There is a way to execute `setTranslation()` after my http GET request?

Comment: Shouldn't you call `this.translate.use(this.browser_language)` after calling `setTranslation()` to be able display `pippo`?

Comment: already tried but it doesn't work @UnsinkableSam